# Calling Haskell function in Yesod with onclick

Tags: haskell, yesod

Is there a possibility to call a Haskell function in Yesod with the "onclick" setting?

The function I want to call:

`save_all :: WidgetT App IO[()]
save_all = mapM save_cur_answers (exam_questions exam_1)`

```
save_cur_answers :: Question -> WidgetT App IO()
save_cur_answers quest = do
q_box1 <- runInputPost $ ireq checkBoxField (answer_id ((answer_list quest) !! 0))
q_box2 <- runInputPost $ ireq checkBoxField (answer_id ((answer_list quest) !! 1))
q_box3 <- runInputPost $ ireq checkBoxField (answer_id ((answer_list quest) !! 2))
q_box4 <- runInputPost $ ireq checkBoxField (answer_id ((answer_list quest) !! 3))

setSession (question_id quest) $ bool_to_cookie [q_box1, q_box2, q_box3, q_box4]
```

in

```
<input type="radio" onclick="save_all" name="tabs" id="tab#{question_id quest}">
```

I want to get the results of all checkboxes and save it in a cookie everytime I click on the radio button. The `save_cur_answers` looks up the checkboxes with the unique answer_id, returns the `Bool` value and stores all 4 of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly the way you are describing. You can have `onclick` use some Javascript to make an AJAX call, which will trigger a handler function to be run.